# Cannot get query var 'post_type' to work

Tags: custom-post-types, search, urls

I am struggling to get the post_type query var (as referenced from http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) to work.

This is what the URL looks like:

```
?s=microsoft&post_type=bg
```

but it just returns all results from all post types.

Filtering by category works fine, e.g.

```
?s=microsoft&category_name=business
```

Please can anyone help with this?

Comment: I have solved this issue, my functions.php was calling

     `$query->set('post_type', array('page', 'bg', 'sc', 'news', 'events', 'lp'));`

on pre_get_posts which was overwriting the query var.

Comment: please answer your own question and mark it correct :)